# Cor números chartjs

Tags: php, javascript, html5, chartjs

Fiz um código em js e php porém não estou achando onde que está setando a cor dos números que mostram os valores em cima dos pontos das linhas do gráfico. Preciso saber em que momento que seta a cor vermelha nos números.

Código:

```
<div class="large-12 columns">
    <div class="header panel">
        <canvas id="canvasBG"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>

<script>

var dataBG = {
    labels: [ <?php foreach($class->Lista("BG") as $dados){ echo '"'.$dados->getQtTotalOrigem().'",'; }?> ],
    datasets: [{
        label: "Entregas",
        backgroundColor: window.chartColors.red,
        borderColor: window.chartColors.red,
        data: [ <?php foreach($class->Lista("BG") as $dados){ echo $dados->getQtTotalDestino().','; }?> ],
        fill: false,            
    }, {
        label: "Efetivas",
        backgroundColor: window.chartColors.blue,
        borderColor: window.chartColors.blue,
        data: [ <?php foreach($class->Lista("BG") as $dados){ echo $dados->getQtTotalFinal().','; }?> ],
        fill: false,
    }, {
        label: "Veiculos",
        fill: false,
        backgroundColor: window.chartColors.green,
        borderColor: window.chartColors.green,
        data: [ <?php foreach($class->Lista("BG") as $dados){ echo $dados->getQtAtrasadoOrigem().','; }?> ],
    }]

};

var ctx = document.getElementById("canvasBG").getContext("2d");
window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: dataBG,
    options: {

        "hover": {
            "animationDuration": 0
        },
        "animation": {
            "duration": 1000,
            "onComplete": function() {
                var chartInstance = this.chart,
                ctx = chartInstance.ctx;

                ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontStyle, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
                ctx.textAlign = 'center';
                ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';


                this.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset, i) {
                    var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
                    meta.data.forEach(function(bar, index) {
                        var data = dataset.data[index];
                        ctx.fillText(data, bar._model.x, bar._model.y - 1);
                    });
                });
            }
        },

        responsive: true,
        title:{
            display:true,
            text:'Apuração de entregas'
        },
        legend: {
            "display": true,
            position: 'bottom',
        },
        tooltips: {
            "enabled": false
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                display: true,
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: false,
                    labelString: 'Month'
                }
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                display: true,
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: false,
                    labelString: 'Value'
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Gráfico:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você quer alterar só as cores dos números?

Comment: Isso mesmo, só os números.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O chartsjs possui uma série de atributos com funcionalidades especificas na questão de aparencia do objeto renderizado.

Um exemplo para as `'labels'` da legenda (retirada da própria documentação):

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    options: {
        legend: {
            display: true,
            labels: {
                fontColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

No seu caso, você quer modificar a cor do `dataset`, a função `backgroundColor` é um função de `'dataset'` não da `'label'`, por isso sempre fica com a mesma cor, no caso, pega a cor informada na última chamada.

Para conseguir o resultado desejado, deve-se informar as cores como uma propriedade de `dataset`, mas em forma de `array`, uma cor para cada `label`:

```
data: {
    labels: ["Entregas", "Efetivas", "Veiculos"],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Dados',
        data: ['Dados'],
        backgroundColor: [
            '#D3E4F3'
        ],
        borderColor: [
            '#000',
            '#999',
            '#ccc'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
    }]
}
```

A mesma coisa vale para qualquer atributo de dataset, não se passa junto aos dados, e sim uma array para cada função que você quer fora dos dados.

Exemplo funcional:

```js
Chart.defaults.global.legend.labels.usePointStyle = true;

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
    labels: ["Entregas", "Efetivas", "Veiculos"],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Dados',
        data: [17,9,29],
        backgroundColor: [
            '#fff',
            '#000',
            '#ccc'
        ],
        borderColor: [
            '#000',
            '#999',
            '#ccc'
        ],
        fontColor: [
            '#000',
            '#999',
            '#ccc'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
    }]
},
    options: {
        legend: {
            display: true,
            position: 'bottom',
            labels: {
                fontColor: '#333'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Fontes:

[Doc. Sobre estilos](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html)

Recomendação de leitura do porque não alterar as cores se não souber o que está fazendo:

[8% Better — Data Graphics and Colour Vision](http://betweentwobrackets.com/data-graphics-and-colour-vision/)

> ATUALIZAÇÃO

Para definir a cor dos values é preciso seguir:

```
    datasets: [
            {
              label: '# of Votes',
              data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            borderWidth: 1,
            backgroundColor: '#000',
            borderColor: '#000'
            },  
                {
                    label: '# of Points',
                    data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
                    borderWidth: 1,
            backgroundColor: '#ccc',
            borderColor: '#ccc'

                }
    ]
```

Porém, para charts em `'LINE'` ele vai sempre colocar uma unica cor a todas as lines, não há na documentação referente a `type='line'` nenhuma função indicando para mudar a cor do `'value'`, ou seja, não há como, repare bem que esta definindo apenas cor da `borda` e do `background`, nunca do `label` do `valor`.

> Por que todas as cores ficaram iguais ?

Porque você definiu o `'backgroudColor'`, e a line com maiores valores, vao ter seu `backgroundColor` a frente das demais, perceba que no seu exemplo, se o valor das `'efetivas'` se tornar maior que o de `'entregas'` a cor dos `values` irá ficar azul.

Isso pode ser um bug do plugin, ou mesmo que ele tenha sido feito para operar assim, resumindo, você não vai conseguir mudar a cor do values em um `type=line` sem alterar/extender o plugin.

PS: pode haver gambiarras pra isso, mas desconheço algum modo que vá funcionar.

Comment: Fiz e não da certo, me mostra um exemplo funcionando com type line não com type bar. E outra, o que eu quero mudar é só a fonte dos números acima.

Comment: Coloca esse gráfico funcionando no jsfiddle com alguns dados, vc só não ta sabendo onde por a cor, ai eu ja arrumo la

Comment: @Kevin.F leia a atualização da resposta.

Comment: Agora eu entendi.

Answer (score 0):

Está neste trecho:

```
var dataBG = {
    labels: [ <?php foreach($class->Lista("BG") as $dados){ echo '"'.$dados->getQtTotalOrigem().'",'; }?> ],
    datasets: [{
        label: "Entregas",
        backgroundColor: window.chartColors.red, <-- Aqui
        borderColor: window.chartColors.red, <-- Aqui
        fontColor:  window.chartColors.red, <!-- Edit 1: Implementação do código. 
        data: [ <?php foreach($class->Lista("BG") as $dados){ echo $dados->getQtTotalDestino().','; }?> ],
        fill: false,            
    }, {
        label: "Efetivas",
        backgroundColor: window.chartColors.blue, <-- Aqui
        borderColor: window.chartColors.blue, <-- Aqui
        data: [ <?php foreach($class->Lista("BG") as $dados){ echo $dados->getQtTotalFinal().','; }?> ],
        fill: false,
    }, {
        label: "Veiculos",
        fill: false,
        backgroundColor: window.chartColors.green, <-- Aqui
        borderColor: window.chartColors.green, <-- Aqui
        data: [ <?php foreach($class->Lista("BG") as $dados){ echo $dados->getQtAtrasadoOrigem().','; }?> ],
    }]

};
```

Caso queira utilizar uma cor diferente é só utilizar:

```
backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
borderColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
```

Comment: Ta mais ai que está, mudei sómente o primeiro e mudou de todos números as cores.

Comment: Posta a alteração!

Comment: Envés de `backgroundColor: window.chartColors.red` coloquei `backgroundColor: window.chartColors.orange` e ficou todos laranjas não sómente de uma linha do gráfico.

Comment: Tenta utilizar o rgb.

Comment: Já tentei, acontece a mesma coisa.

Comment: Edita sua pergunta com a alteração. Pra eu ver o cotexto geral

Comment: Fiz a alteração, se não functionar tenta só color.

Comment: Testei e testei só com color também não mudou nada.